# React / React Native log in to firebase auth getting warning about React State Update on Unmounted Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build a login experience with firebase auth and React Native. But I am getting the following warning:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

This is the Loading screen function that waits for firebase auth to reroute the user to the login screen if the user has not logged in or to the home screen once they have logged in.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

      if (user) {
        navigation.replace("Home");
      } else {
        navigation.replace("Sign In");
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

This is the function that calls the login function from firebase auth.

```
  async function signIn(email, password, auth) {
      try {
        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERR: ", err)
       return err.message
      }
    }
```

And here is the function that submits the form to attempt the login functionality.

```
const handlePress = () => {
    if (readyToSubmit) {
      if (!email) {
        setEmailError('Email field is required.');
      } else if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        setEmailError('You must enter a valid email.');
      } else if (!password) {
        setPasswordError('Password is required');
        setPassword('');
      } else {
 
        setPassword('');
        signIn(email, password, authContext).then((msg) => {
          switch (msg) {
            case 'success':
              console.log('Success');
              break;
            case 'auth/user-not-found':
              setEmailError('User Not found');
              break;
            case 'auth/wrong-password':
              setPasswordError('Wrong Password');
              break;
            default:
              console.log('MSG:', msg);
              setPasswordError(msg);
          }
        
      }
    } else {
      setPasswordError('Please fill out the form');
    }
  };
```

Can anyone help me clean up this code and give a more elegant solution to avoid this warning?

Comment: Maybe you can try to navigate inside `handlePress` in the 'success' case.

Comment: You're updating the state in error cases, but the navigation could be happening before, causing the state update on an unmounted component.

Comment: Well, you are missing a cleanup function from the `useEffect` to unsubscribe when that component unmounts. I don't know if that's part of the cause or not since you've not included a compete or reproducible code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese I hear you. And you are right ablout the useEffect cleanup, I just can't figure out how to get all of this into a useEffect and retain the state objects when I need them and. all the handlePress function. And I also hear you on the minimal reproducible example situation, but creating that seems like a mammoth task and i would have to set up a fake firebase account to begin to reproduce this. Trust me I thought about it.

Comment: @RameshReddy thanks for your comments. These are things I know, I'm just trying to figure out how other people have done this since I know there are folks out there with this exact stack that have had to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution that removes the warning. And the comments on the question did help me consider this, but it still feels a little dirty. Still if anyone comes across this, maybe it will help them. I'm still hoping for a better solution but in the loading screen if I put a setTimeout function around the redirect, it does remove the warning, which I believe shows that it is navigating before the component is able to unmount.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    authContext.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

     if (user) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            navigation.replace("Home");
        }, 200)
    
     } else {
        navigation.replace("Sign In");
     }
   });
 }, []);
```